# Illegal characters

Tags: google-authenticator, google-2fa

I always make copies of my 2FA keys.

Now I have two phones. I have installed Google Authenticator on the second (newer) phone using the 2FA keys so that it doesn't matter which phone I am using. They are both synchronised and return identical OTPs (of course).

But today I set up a 2FA for a new site. When I enter the 2FA key on the second phone, I get an "Illegal character" error message every time I get to the "8". Does anyone know why that could be?